# Automatically connect to VPN when connecting to WiFi?

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, automation, vpn

My university has an open WiFi that requires me to log into a specific VPN before I can access the internet.

Is there any built-in way or app that allows me to specify which VPN I want to start together with a certain WiFi connection? (Similar to Ubuntu's option to combine a WiFi with a VPN) Right now I have to start the VPN manually every time, and if I loose connectivity, the VPN will not automatically reconnect together with the network connection.

I am using cyanogenmod 10.2.0

**EDIT:**

To clarify, this is what the option looks like in Ubuntu's network manager:

[image]

I want to achieve a similar effect in Android/Cyanogenmod.

Comment: I'm not sure if this could help, but Avast secureline (http://www.avast.com/en-us/secureline-android) provides a VPN service and automatically connects when it detects an open wi-fi

Comment: I am not looking for a VPN provider. I have an existing VPN service I want to automatically connect to. So apps that only work for a specific VPN provider won't help me unfortunately.

Comment: I supposed that, but I wasn't sure. Sorry for the inaccurate answer.

Comment: This is on the to-do list for [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) ([source](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/todo.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Feature of VPNroot does exactly do what you want:

- auto connect/disconnect on a specific WiFi (only for Pro)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.did.vpnroot&hl=en

Comment: Sounds awesome, but unfortunately I was unable to establish the VPN connection with this app even after trying out all possible settings I could think of. It works without problems with the built-in CM VPN tool, so I am not sure why this app does not work.

Comment: Which CM build do you use? Stable & official or some unofficial build?

Comment: Stable and official, on a Galaxy S3. The exact CM version number is in the question.

Comment: That's your problem -- you're running the "stable and official" version. You need Root for VPNroot to work. Go to Settings - About  and tap the build number until it enables Developer options, then go to the Developer menu and enable root for apps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like with privateinternetaccess VPN you can do it. You have to enter details given by the vpn provider into the smartphone settings so the app is not required:

[Android-How to use " Allways-on VPN"](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/18700/android-how-to-use-allways-on-vpn)

I guess other vpn providers can give you the connection setting to enter on your android device. If you use an app, I guess it's not that straightforward.

[Enable VPN on airplane mode, before connecting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167470/enable-vpn-on-airplane-mode-before-connecting/)

Comment: Do you know why when I tick "Always-On VPN" the button Connect get greyed out? Without this checkbox enabled it connects smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling too and today I finally found a solution (may be a bite late for you but may help others) that works for my **stock rooted android device 4.4.2** :

- Install [**E-Robot**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.robot), a powerful tasker that have really great features
- Then install [**Secure Settings**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin), that will appear as a third party actions on E-Robot. There, you can choose *Root Action* and *VPN*, which should be supported.

You can now configure E-Robot to connect to a chosen VPN if an app from a defined group is launched/gains focus, and to disconnect otherwise!

Comment: Sorry, just realised I misread, but what I said is still a working solution for you : it's possible to define a global variable expression equivalent to *<Current Wifi> equals <School Wifi>*, and set as an event *Wifi connected* with condition your global variable, that'll launch VPN connection; and then do the same to disconnect it ;)