# Enable VPN on airplane mode, before connecting

Tags: wi-fi, data-connection, vpn, airplane-mode

I want to set the VPN (in my case vpnunlimitedapp) so it connects through the VPN the second I enable WIFI or 4G. Currently, I have to go online for a moment and then I'm allowed to enable the VPN. How can I remedy this so no bit of information get exposed?

Comment: VPN can only be created when you have internet connectivity, so exposure is unavoidable.

Comment: Shadowsocks seems to be able to stay "connected" regardless of network state.

Comment: @beeshyams See my own answer, it looks like you  can but you need to  know the VPN details and configure it on Settings, so I guess it automatically connects to VPN before going to the internet.
If you use the app, then it's when you get exposed.

Comment: Seen. Thanks, I was looking it specific to your app in question- I use adguard, which is switched on the moment it is connected to net and creates a VPN

Comment: @AndyYan: Interesting. Can you verify that please? If so, then my understanding of VPN app function is flawed

Comment: @beeshyams I just went to verify: on Android, turning it on requires network, but subsequently it can work in the background regardless of network status, and work immediately when network comes on. Even better, on PC it just connects, no restrictions. I do think SS is not your typical VPN - I will look it up too.

Comment: I've updated my own answer with further links.

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like with privateinternetaccess VPN you can do it. You have to enter details given by the vpn provider into the smartphone settings so the app is not required:

[Android-How to use " Allways-on VPN"](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/18700/android-how-to-use-allways-on-vpn)

Related information:

[Force VPN usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13074/force-vpn-usage)

[Connect to a virtual private network (VPN)](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819573?hl=en)

[Automatically connect to VPN when connecting to WiFi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/74752/automatically-connect-to-vpn-when-connecting-to-wifi)

**EDITED LATER:**

TunnelBear VPN has a vigilant mode designed to keep your location and data private in the brief seconds while TunnelBear is connecting and reconnecting. Currently the Vigilant feature is available on our Mac OS X and Windows desktop apps, as well as our Android app. You can find this within your Settings/Preferences panel. To turn it on, make sure that it's enabled:
[TunnelBear's Online Privacy Blog: A More Vigilant TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/blog/vigilant/)

[VPN Unlimited](https://www.vpnunlimitedapp.com/) has a similar option. Just go to 'Settings' -> 'VPN Reconnect Settings' -> choose 'WiFi is ON'.